# Symfony2 : use translator in a twig filter extension

Tags: symfony, filter, translation

I'm trying to use translation in a custom twig filter like this

```
public function formatTime($timestamp)
{
    $str = date('j %\m%',$timestamp);
    $str = str_replace($str, '%m%', $this->get('translator')->trans('month'.date('m', $timestamp) ) );
    return $str;
}
```

offcourse get is unknown function. 
Should I make my Extension aware of the environment or simply request translation class to make it available ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can inject a `translator` service into your class:

```xml
<service id="acme.extension" class="Acme\Twig\Extensions\FormatterExtension">
    <tag name="twig.extension"/>
    <argument type="service" id="translator"/>
</service>
```

And then store an instance of translator in the protected field and use it later:

```php
public function formatTime($timestamp)
{
    $str = date('j %\m%',$timestamp);
    $str = str_replace($str, '%m%', $this->translator->trans('month'.date('m', $timestamp) ) );
    return $str;
}
```

**UPD1:** configuration for YAML service definition:

```
acme.extension:
    class: Acme\Twig\Extensions\FormatterExtension
    arguments: [@translator]
    tags:
        - name: twig.extension
```

Comment: My service is defined in a yml configuration file, I assume it should like this : 

    twig.extension.rc_extension:
      class: Acme\Twig\Extensions\FormatterExtension
      arguments:
        - { type: service, id: translator }
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }

Comment: Dependency Injection tag is `@translator.default` by Symfony 2.6, the `@translator` tag refers to LoggingTranslator now.

Answer (score 3):

I would define your class as a service using the service container. You can then pass in the translator service as an argument like this:

in services.yml:

```
services:
    your.class.identification.key:
       class: \your\class\name
       arguments: [@translator]
```

afterwards, the translator will be available via the code  you provided above.

Comment: Dependency Injection tag is `@translator.default` by Symfony 2.6, the `@translator` tag refers to LoggingTranslator now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update @Alexander answer. Don't forget to put

```
private $translator;
public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator) {
   $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the controller layer `$this->get()` calls the get method from the translator service.

In order to mimic this behavior, you can set dependency injection and have the dependency container injected to your constructor. Once you've done this, you can get the translator by using something like this: `$this->container->get('translator')`.